# MongoDB how do I reduce application logging

Tags: spring, mongodb, logging

I have a web server application that uses MongoDB 3.4.  I am using slf4j with Spring Boot to manage the application log.  I believe Logback is the default logger for Spring Boot when using the slf4j facade.  I have my logging level set to INFO for now.  I am having trouble trying to reduce MongoDB logging.  Over time, I get 1000's of MongoDB INFO log entries for every 1 or 2 application log entries making debugging difficult.  I looked at the MongoDB log file and found the same issue.  It had thousands of INFO log entries.  I executed the following mongodb shell command,

```
db.runCommand({
    setParameter: 0,
    logComponentVerbosity: {
        "verbosity" : 0,
        "accessControl" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "command" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "control" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "executor" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "geo" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "index" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "network" : {
                "verbosity" : 0,
                "asio" : {
                        "verbosity" : 0
                },
                "bridge" : {
                        "verbosity" : 0
                }
        },
        "query" : {
                "verbosity" :0
        },
        "replication" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "sharding" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "storage" : {
                "verbosity" : 0,
                "journal" : {
                        "verbosity" : 0
                }
        },
        "write" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "ftdc" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        },
        "tracking" : {
                "verbosity" : 0
        }
    }
})
```

This dramatically lowered the number of MongoDB log entries.  However, it did not affect the application log entries.  I am still getting a very high number of not very useful MongoDB INFO log entries.  Anyone know how I can reduce the number of MongoDB application log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
logging.level.org.mongodb=ERROR
```

in your `application.properties` file.

Comment: Worked like a charm!